# How i can draw some line in Qt 3?

Tags: c++, qt, graphics

I would like to draw a waveform with the Qt Editor, in practice they are very close lines with different height that does not depart from the bottom but from the center of the "graphic". How does it with Qt?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Qt3 is definitely obsolete. Use Qt5 preferably ([Qt5.3](http://qt-project.org/qt5/qt53) in august 2014)

Then, read more about [Qt Graphics View](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/graphicsview.html) and [QGraphicsItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html) see the [examples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/examples-graphicsview.html) (or also the [Qt OpenGL example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtgui-openglwindow-example.html))